# Unable to auto/manually load database library in codeigniter

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter

I'm unable to load database library in CodeIgniter's default extracted code

1) via autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

2) Inside controller via

```
$this->load->library("database");
```

or

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->database();
```

**Error message:** The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

**Environment:** CodeIgniter 2.1.3, PHP 5.2.13 on IIS (ISAPI), MySQL (5.0.45-community-nt), Plesk.

I have confirmed that code written in plain PHP allows me to access the database.

As soon as I remove this library, I can see the page. I am able to load other libraries like session, and my custom library as well. Any ideas what I am missing?

Here're my database config settings:

```
$active_record = TRUE;  

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';  
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';  
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';  
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';  
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';  
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';  
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;  
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';  
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';  
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';  
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';  
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: there is a function duplicate in your code or might be a php error

Comment: Did you test your Codeigniter code locally? .. If yes It should display more about the error.

Comment: have you configure your database setting properly, check this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: Agreed, most probably db config error. Can you post your database config file?

Comment: I've added the database settings in the question. Using the same username and password I can connect using plain PHP but CodeIgniter gives me error (when logs enabled) that `mysql_pconnect() has been disabled for security reasons` and `unable to connect to database`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can anyway check your server logs or you can  enable CI logs by config.php

go to line 206 of your config.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

put the value to 4 and check if you have a `775 chmod /logs` directory in your `/application` folder, if not `create that`, CI will automatically create log files inside that directory.

you'll be able to check any CI error in this way

AS YOU REPORTED FROM the log file

change, database.php line 50 under /config directory:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
```

to

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: With logging enabled, I get Severity: `Warning --> mysql_pconnect() has been disabled for security reasons ...\mysql\mysql_driver.php 91` and `ERROR - 2012-12-27 02:25:09 --> Unable to connect to the database`. However, using same username and password I can connect to the database in plain PHP.

Comment: ok check the database.php line 50 **$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;** try with FALSE

Comment: @Ali do not forget to check answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

OK, based on the logs, when I set

`$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;`

to

`$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;`

the database library got loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and spend about 5 hours troubleshooting digging through stack trace and mysql logs. It turns out the cause was unrelated but I am posting here to save anyone the trouble I had.

I build my VM from scratch and I apparently forgot to install the MySQL driver for php5. The symptoms I had are exactly the same, a blank screen - no response at all. To anyone seeing this in the future, make sure you have the mysql driver!! A 30 second fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have your php5-mysql installed. 
In your EC2 or your VM, remember to install php5-mysql

> sudo apt-get install php5-mysql